# How to run a shell which will stop current process?

Tags: linux, shell, systemctl

The program `processA` is a Linux service, launched by "`systemctl start processA`".
This process will call `std::system` to run a shell script to upgrade software.
The script will run "`systemctl`" to stop `processA` first, then replace some executable files, finally restart `processA`.

The problem is that when "`systemctl stop processA`" is executed, the script is also terminated.
How to solve it?

I had tried to run the script file in terminal; it works. So there is not a problem with the script.

```cpp
  //this is how the script is called
  int rs = std::system("/usr/bin/update_server.sh upgrade \"/tmp/firmware\" > \"/tmp/upgrade.log\" 2>&1");
```

Comment: You probably need to establish which signals `systemctl stop processA` sends to the child processes, and then arrange for the script to ignore those signals.  If `systemctl` is insistent, it may send a crescendo of signals, such as `SIGHUP`, `SIGTERM` and finally `SIGKILL`.  If it gets stroppy enough to send `SIGKILL`, there's nothing your script can do, but `SIGHUP` and `SIGTERM` could be ignored, allowing the script to continue (and replace the executables), then run `systemctl start processA` again.  Step 1 is to record which signals are sent (if possible).  Then you can deal with it.

Comment: If the manual page for [`systemctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html) is to be trusted, the `-s` option specifies which signal is to be sent, and the default is `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 0):

systemd will also kill child processes (after all, that's what's usually desired), so you can't do the upgrade from the service.

You can, however create a [oneshot service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) to upgrade the binary that conflicts with the main service. To upgrade, you stop the service, run the upgrade service and then start the service again.